# My TF.exe is strangely gone 0KB and not operating

Tags: batch-file, tfs, windows-10, tf-cli

I have been trying to automate some deployment and regularly used `tf.exe` through `.bat` files. I recently started getting "this app can't run on your pc" on my `.bat` files and upon checking I saw my `tf.exe` is 0KB.

following is the example of a ```.bat`` files I usually ran.

```
SET tfs=http://vm03:8080/tfs

SET chg= %1

"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\TF.exe" 
 changeset /server:%tfs% %chg% /noprompt
```

I am using 64-bit windows 10. anyway I can have tf.exe reinstalled? and can anyone explain what happened?

edit: I have another instance of visual studio 17, and I am using its `tf.exe` however what happened to my original `tf.exe` is still unknown. Anything to help me understand will be great.

Comment: Which TFS version do you use?

Comment: i am using TFS 2015

Comment: Try to install VS 2017 and use his tf.exe

Comment: `used tf.exe through .bat files`: maybe there is an error in one of your batch files, so that, under circumstances, it overwrites the `tf.exe` file. Like for example `type NUL > tf.exe` of course not literally, that would be "duh!", but maybe through some more hideous means. You could try to remove "write" permissions for _anyone_ (even admins) for the `tf.exe` file and watch what happens over time. Maybe you catch an error message somewhere. What happend is otherwise a pretty broad question.